# call of static class inside _callstatic not working

Tags: php

I'm working on a plugin system, and at the moment I'm forced to use `call_user_func_array`. And that is slow and use memory.

My function is working, and looks like this:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $plugins = self::_checkEventCache($method);

    if( count($plugins) ) :
    foreach( $plugins as $p ):
        $tmp =  call_user_func_array(array(self::$_installedPlugins[$p], $method), array(&$args));
        endforeach;
    endif;

self::$_current_event = $method;
}
```

My question is how can I call this directly or make this speed up? I will never know how many arguments that will be attached later.

Any solution to get rid of `call_user_func_array`?

`$tmp =` is not working on this either. Earlier - when I didn't use static, it returned a value. The old code I used was like this:

```
$tmp = $this->_installedPlugins[$p]->{$method}($args);

if( $tmp !== NULL ){
    $this->_event_result[$method] = $tmp;
}
```

I need to get the same results now when I use static class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that you´re not doing anything with $tmp variable. But it should be assigned some value.

Anyway I´m not sure whether your plugins method calls are also static or not, so I´m gonna describe both cases.
First non-static plugin method calls:

In this case you can use similar method call like in your old code

```
$tmp = self::$_installedPlugins[$p]->{$method}($args);
```

And now the case with statuc plugin calls:

Now it´s a little more tricky, PHP obviously won´t let you have two sets of :: in one expression, so you have to bypass it like this:

```
$plug= self::$_installedPlugins[$p];
$tmp = $plug::{$method}($args);
```

I´ve tested it on PHP 5.4 and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I searched for. I also had this problems with :: in on expression. So, problem solved.